# Increase StackSwitcher size in gtk3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

I have a Gtk.StackSwitcher in my python code, and I would like to increase its size to have biggers icons :

[image: small icons in stackSwitcher]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1448396978.png))</sub>

Here is the relevant code :

```
    stack = Gtk.Stack()  # catégories d'applications
    stack.set_transition_type(Gtk.StackTransitionType.SLIDE_UP_DOWN)
    stack.set_transition_duration(1000)
    # some code
    for c in categories:
        icon = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(c['icon'],Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG)
        icon.show()
        stack.add_titled(icon, c['label'], c['label'])
        stack.child_set_property(icon, "icon-name", c['icon'])

    stack_switcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher(homogeneous=True)
    stack_switcher.set_stack(stack)
```

I can't find anything in the documentation to change icon (or label) size.

Answer (score 2):

> gtk_image_set_pixel_size ()
>
> void gtk_image_set_pixel_size (GtkImage *image,
>                             gint pixel_size); Sets the pixel size to use for named icons. If the pixel size is set to a value != -1, it is used
>   instead of the icon size set by gtk_image_set_from_icon_name().
>
> Parameters
>
> image a GtkImage   pixel_size the new pixel size   Since: 2.6

`gtk.image.set_pixel_size(256)` should do the trick.